# What GNU/Linux command-line tool would I use for performing a search and replace on a file?

Tags: regex, linux, sed, gnu

What GNU/Linux command-line tool would I use for performing a search and replace on a file?

Can the search text, and replacement, be specified in a regex format?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

```
sed 's/a.*b/xyz/g;' old_file > new_file
```

[GNU sed](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/) (which you probably have) is even more versatile:

```
sed -r --in-place 's/a(.*)b/x\1y/g;' your_file
```

Here is a brief explanation of those options:

> **-i[SUFFIX], --in-place[=SUFFIX]**
> edit files in place (makes backup if extension supplied)
>
> **-r, --regexp-extended**
> use extended regular expressions in the script.

The [FreeBSD](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sed&sektion=1), [NetBSD](https://man.netbsd.org/sed.1) and [OpenBSD](http://man.openbsd.org/sed.1) versions also supports these options.

If you want to learn more about sed, [Cori](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155934/what-gnu-linux-command-line-tool-would-i-use-for-performing-a-search-and-replace/155944#155944) has suggested [this tutorial](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html).

Comment: I didn't know about the -r switch to allow extended regex - handy!  Also, -i is a shortcut for --in-place.

Comment: And use cori's link above if you want to learn more.  sed is more lightweight than perl afaik

Answer (score 28):

Perl was invented for this:

```
perl -pi -e 's/foo/bar/g;' *.txt
```

Any normal s/// pattern in those single quotes. You can keep a backup with something like this:

```
perl -pi.bak -e 's/foo/bar/g;' *.txt
```

Or pipeline:

```
cat file.txt | perl -ne 's/foo/bar/g;' | less
```

But that's really more sed's job.

Answer (score 6):

Consider Ruby as an alternative to Perl.  It stole most of Perl's one-liner commandline args (`-i`, `-p`, `-l`, `-e`, `-n`) and auto-sets `$_` for you like Perl does and has plenty of regex goodness.  Additionally Ruby's syntax may be more comfortable and easier to read or write than Perl's or sed's.  (Or not, depending on your tastes.)

`ruby -pi.bak -e '$_.gsub!(/foo|bar/){|x| x.upcase}' *.txt`

vs.

`perl -pi.bak -e 's/(foo|bar)/\U\1/g' *.txt`

In many cases when dealing with one-liners, performance isn't enough of an issue to care whether you use lightweight sed or heavyweight Perl or heaveier-weight Ruby.  Use whatever is easiest to write.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful example! I think it could be simplified (slightly) by: `ruby -pi.bak -e 'gsub(/foo|bar/){|x| x.upcase}' *.txt`  (eg, removing the `$_`).

Answer (score 5):

[sed](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html), the stream editor, and yes, it uses regex.