# How to config Jaxb to ignore the use Attribute?

Tags: java, configuration, jaxb

I have a XSD scheme but I cannot change the Scheme 

```
<xs:attribute name="zbpName" type="Zbp_NC" use="required"/>
<xs:attribute name="zbpType" type="ZBPTYP_CL" use="required"/
```

Generation of Java-Classes works, but I want to ignore the Attribute use="required”. Is there a way to ignore this?

I want to get this result when I marshal.

```
<protectionPoint zbpName="Protection Point - 0">
```

But in the moment I get this result….

```
<protectionPoint zbpNotes="" zbpStation="" zbpInterlockingName="" zbpType="" zbpName="Protection Point - 0">
```

It is because the generated Clasess have this Annotation.

```
@XmlAttribute(name = "zbpStation", required = true)
```

But the should look like this…

```
@XmlAttribute(name = "zbpStation")
```

Thanks for your help ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can just create your own class with correct annotations and use it instead of old one, e.g.:

```
public interface TestInterface {
    Integer getField();     
}

public class TestClass implements TestInterface{

    @Attribute(required = true)
    private Integer field;

    public TestClass() {
    }

    public TestClass(Integer field) {
        this.field = field;
    }

    public Integer getField() {
        return field;
    }

    public void setField(Integer field) {
        this.field = field;
    }
}

public class NewTestClass implements TestInterface{

    @Attribute
    private Integer field;

    public NewTestClass() {
    }

    public NewTestClass(Integer field) {
        this.field = field;
    }

    public Integer getField() {
        return field;
    }

    public void setField(Integer field) {
        this.field = field;
    }
}
```

Actually, it depends on what access you have to target class.

Comment: This "use" is not easy, as JAXB classes should be in one package. I would say, one needs to correct the Java class after it is being generated.

Comment: You cannot remove annotations in runtime, so it must be done manually BEFORE compilation

Comment: But I must do this for many Classes so that is not really an option for me…
Thank you.

Comment: You can search & replaces in .java files [based on regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/186096). But I agree, that using JAXB plugin (as @lexicore suggested) is best idea.

Comment: @dma_k The only problem I see is that its is still a lot of work for many classes. A better option might be to write a plugin which changes the `required` setting for attribute fields.

Answer (score 2):

So you want to `required="false"` but can't change schema? You can use [JAXB2-Basics Annotate Plugin](http://confluence.highsource.org/display/J2B/Annotate+Plugin) version 0.6.3 and higher to achieve this. The customization would look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<jaxb:bindings
    xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:annox="http://annox.dev.java.net"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/bindingschema_2_0.xsd"
    jaxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="xjc annox"
    version="2.1">

    <!-- org.example.TFreeForm @XmlRootElement -->
    <jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="schema.xsd" node="/xs:schema">
        <jaxb:bindings node="xs:complexType[@name='MyType']/xs:attribute[@name='test']">
            <annox:annotate target="field">
                <annox:annotate annox:class="javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute" required="false"/>
            </annox:annotate>
        </jaxb:bindings>
    </jaxb:bindings>

</jaxb:bindings>
```

The 0.6.3 version is not released yet. A snapshot is available [here](http://repository.highsource.org/maven2/snapshots/org/jvnet/jaxb2_commons/jaxb2-basics-annotate/).